# Derivative of the derivative of a neural network w.r.t. itself

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, neural-networks

I'm trying to find the following derivative:

\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial f \partial x}
\end{equation}
where $f$ is a neural network, and $x$ is an input.
To be more accurate, let's say $f$ is a 2-layer neural net with a 1-D output and 1-D input. Then, we can write $f$ as:
$$
f(x) = tanh(xW_1 + b_1)W_2 + b 
$$
I tried deriving the formula for $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ and got the following:
$$
\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = W_2^T\times (W_1^T\circ tanh'(xW_1 + b_1))
$$
where $\circ$ is the element-wise product. Now, I need to take its derivative w.r.t. $f$ itself. Any ideas on how to proceed from here?

---

Edit: As @NinadMunshi pointed out, I intend to find the following derivative after a variable change:
$$
z = tanh(xW_1 + b_1)W_2 + b\\
g = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = W_2^T\times (W_1^T\circ tanh'(xW_1 + b_1))\\
\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} = ?
$$

Comment: what is the definition of derivative with respect to itself ?

Comment: @dezdichado I mean taking the derivative of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ w.r.t. $f$, i.e. $\frac{\partial^2f}{\partial f \partial x}$. In other words, I need the derivatives of $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ w.r.t. the outputs of the last layer of the network. I'm not sure if this is well-defined though...

Comment: The question makes no sense.

Comment: @copper.hat I believe the intention is a variable change. For example take $$f(x) = e^{x^2} = z$$ Then we get $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = 2xe^{x^2} = 2z\sqrt{\log z} \equiv g(z)$$ and $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial z} = 2\sqrt{\log z} + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\log z}} \equiv 2x + \frac{1}{x}$$ to which we can somewhat soundly attach the abuse of notation $$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial f \partial x} = 2x + \frac{1}{x}$$

Comment: @copper.hat At least for functions $f:\Bbb{R}\to\Bbb{R}$, this operator reduces to the logarithmic derivative of the derivative i.e. $\frac{f''(x)}{f'(x)}$

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$: Consider the case where $W_i,b_i\in\Bbb{R}$. Then the solution is simply

$$\frac{\partial^2 f}{\partial f \partial x} = -2W_1W_2\tanh(W_1x+b_1)$$

Now how would you adapt this answer from scalars to vector functions that act component wise?